# Spring FeignClient throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/ConnectionPool

Tags: spring-boot, okhttp, feign

My spring boot rest application is given from time to time an warning "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/ConnectionPool" that does not impact the application, but it also gives an ERROR while communicating with another microservice using Feign.

I don't have the dependency below that has the class
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.0.0-RC1

In my local environtment it works (probably does not use okhttp3/ConnectionPool), but in production environtment does not.

I didn't understand why springs tries to use this ConnectionPool that does not exists in the dependency.

Please, check the stack trace below:

1. Warning

```
    2019-11-20 05:04:03.669  WARN [service-xxxxxx,,,] 8 --- [AsyncReporter(org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.sender.RestTemplateSender@1c8e2850)] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : [env:PROD] [id:] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connPoolFactory' defined in org.springframework.cloud.commons.httpclient.HttpClientConfiguration$OkHttpClientConfiguration: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/ConnectionPool
```

2. ERROR

```
    2019-11-15 14:08:57.109 ERROR [service-zzzzzzzzz,7c8acfd5e2d4769c,34d5331c31d39caa,true] 8 --- [XNIO-3 task-39] b.c.t.c.m.a.AbstractApiExceptionHandler  : [env:PROD] [id:] Error creating bean with name 'connPoolFactory' defined in org.springframework.cloud.commons.httpclient.HttpClientConfiguration$OkHttpClientConfiguration: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/ConnectionPool
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connPoolFactory' defined in org.springframework.cloud.commons.httpclient.HttpClientConfiguration$OkHttpClientConfiguration: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/ConnectionPool
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:526)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
            at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.createContext(NamedContextFactory.java:116)
            at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getContext(NamedContextFactory.java:85)
            at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getContext(SpringClientFactory.java:120)
            at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getInstance(NamedContextFactory.java:121)
            at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getInstance(SpringClientFactory.java:110)
            at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getClientConfig(SpringClientFactory.java:67)
            at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.getClientConfig(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:78)
            at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:62)
            at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:97)
            at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
            at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy151.verifyStructure(Unknown Source)
            at br.com.yyy.component.microservice.api.validation.ValidateMsisdn.validateAndReturnCustomerId(ValidateMsisdn.java:39)
            at br.com.yyy.component.microservice.api.validation.ValidateMsisdn.validateAdmId(ValidateMsisdn.java:84)
            at br.com.yyy.component.microservice.api.validation.ValidateMsisdn.validate(ValidateMsisdn.java:70)
            at br.com.xxxxx.component.profiling.AbstractProfiling.processGateway(AbstractProfiling.java:301)
            at br.com.xxxxx.component.profiling.AbstractProfiling.profiling(AbstractProfiling.java:146)
            at br.com.yyy.component.profiling.ProfilingAspect.aroundService(ProfilingAspect.java:50)
            at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor220.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
            at br.com.yyy.service.zzzzzzzzz.api.tttttttDelegateService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42f8f6d5.customerBillIdGet(<generated>)
            at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor227.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
            at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:470)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
            at br.com.yyy.service.zzzzzzzzz.api.tttttttDelegateService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0a2f862.customerBillIdGet(<generated>)
            at br.com.yyy.service.zzzzzzzzz.api.ttttttt.customerBillIdGet(ttttttt.java:44)
            at br.com.yyy.service.zzzzzzzzz.api.ttttttt$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a46e9035.invoke(<generated>)
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:97)
            at br.com.xxxxx.component.profiling.AbstractProfiling.profiling(AbstractProfiling.java:164)
            at br.com.yyy.component.profiling.ProfilingAspect.aroundService(ProfilingAspect.java:50)
            at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor220.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
            at br.com.yyy.component.log.request.ServiceRequestLogAspect.log(ServiceRequestLogAspect.java:61)
            at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor226.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
            at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
            at br.com.yyy.service.zzzzzzzzz.api.tttttttController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf7f8448.customerBillIdGet(<generated>)
            at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor225.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter(TraceFilter.java:164)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:64)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
            at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:332)
            at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/ConnectionPool
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:206)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:187)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:125)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:992)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
            ... 150 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.ConnectionPool
            at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
            ... 161 common frames omitted
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you checked the property `feign.okhttp.enabled` in your configuration? By default, Feign tries to use its own http client, and in order to use a different one, you should set the corresponding property. Or if you create feign client with buider, then check the setter for `client` field in it.

Comment: I have'nt. To solve it out I added the okhttp dependency.

Thanks for you tip, I will try it